# How TTY differs from an ordinary file?

Tags: ssh, pty, pseudoterminal

I'm trying to understand `ssh`'s `-t` option:

> `-t`      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-
>                based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing
>                menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local
>                tty.

So, TTY is a device. A way to refer to a TTY is by descriptor (which is obtained by opening the TTY device). STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR are descriptors. But they do not necessarily refer to a TTY device. `-t` option forces them to refer to a TTY device. Is this the correct way of reasoning in order to understand what this option does?

And what is so special about TTY which may not be achieved using ordinary STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR?

An example of use case of `-t` option is welcome.

By which mechanism does `ssh` allocate that TTY? Does `ssh` create new TTY on server or on client? How to check this? (a new node in `/dev/` must appear or something...) And how this new TTY is tied to existing STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR?

Comment: "a tty is a particular kind of device file which implements a number of additional commands (ioctls) beyond read and write..."

Comment: “TTY is a device. It has a descriptor” what do you mean by it has a descriptor?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Midnight Commander, or `dialog` or `whiptail` or Vim, or Emacs, anything that tries to make a TUI.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko you haven't asked for an example anywhere. You're just asking what's special about TTYs. Anyway: `ssh -t some-server vim some-file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `-t` option forces [the standard file descriptors] to refer to a TTY device. Is this the correct way of reasoning in order to understand what this option does?

No. The `-t` option will run the command on the *remote* machine with its stdin/out/err connected to a pseudo-tty slave instead of a pair of pipes.

Running it in a pty is the default if **(a)** no explicit command is given and **(b)** the stdin of the ssh *client* is itself a tty. You need a single `-t` to force tty allocation even when the **(a)** condition is not satisfied, and **two** of them (`-tt`) when **(b)** is not satisfied.

> By which mechanism does ssh allocate that TTY?

By some system-dependent mechanism. Nowadays, it's mostly the standard `master_fd = posix_openpt()` followed by `slave_fd = open(ptsname(master_fd))` [1]

> Does ssh create new TTY on server or on client?

`ssh` **always** create the new pseudo-tty on the **server**, ie on the remote machine. If a pseudo-tty is allocated on the server and the local (client's) stdin is a tty, the local tty will be set to raw mode.

> How to check this? (a new node in `/dev/` must appear or something

Not necessarily. But on a regular linux machine of 2019, a new file will appear under `/dev/pts` for each new pseudo-tty.

> And how this new TTY is tied to existing STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR?

Just like any other file descriptor, with `dup2(slave_fd, 0)`, `dup2(slave_fd, 1)`, etc. `dup2(newfd, oldfd)` will close whatever file `oldfd` was referring to. If a pty was allocated, it will also be made the controlling tty of the remote session.

> An example of use case of `-t` option is welcome.

`ssh -t /bin/bash` on a system where your login shell is `csh`. If you leave out the `-t`, `/bin/bash` will run without prompt, job control, line editing capabilities, etc.

> And what is so special about TTY which may not be achieved using ordinary STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR?

See above ;-)

And a pipe is no more of an "ordinary" stdin than a tty or some other kind of file.

[1] that itself has a lot of problems (with multiple devpts mounts and mount namespaces) that's why the `TIOCGPTPEER` ioctl was added to Linux, which returns a fd referring to the slave without going through the file system.

Comment: I do wonder what, exactly, are the things that can only be done on a tty. There's nothing stopping one from printing prompts or interpreting read bytes as codes for keypresses even if not connected to a tty. But the TTY `ioctl`'s wouldn't be available, so you couldn't set raw/cooked mode or find out the window size? Or something like that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @ilkkachu Everything could be done without a tty. Unix' successor (plan9) got rid of all kinds of ttys completely. But now go on and convince bash, vi, emacs, mc that they don't need a tty ;-)

Comment: ... Sure, one can always create a system where something is possible. But I do mean real Unixy OS's, not hypotheticals (nor Plan 9 (I'm not sure I'd count it Unixy, and I'm also not sure if it's on-topic here))

Comment: On a real Unix system, it's not only that the curses/etc facilities are assumed to be tied to the existence of a tty, it's also the whole job control/session api which has grown around the "controlling tty" abstraction. You cannot simply trash the compatibility with all that, that's why you may need a pty instead of a socket or a pair of pipes.